# Is there any feature in xcode for flavor like in android

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a source code which is use for two applications.
I just have to change the image icons,splash screen,app name and all this sort of things, so i want to know is there any way that xCode support/feature that i am able to dynamically do that like the android studio does.

Here is the help link:

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/build-system-concepts

Comment: what features of "Product Flavors" you are looking forward in Xcode, you might not get all but may be some

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to create a different build target for each "flavor" that you want. There you can specify different `Info.plist`s or build settings for each.

Comment: Can you please give me the steps i am not able to get.
As i have different images inside the application and the name of the application and icons are different as well.